# Mysql: search fullname in a splitted name table

Tags: php, mysql, string, concatenation

I am looking for a method that you can look for a full name in a splitted collumn table

I tried: for example with "michael peter johnson"

```
select firstName,middleName,lastName 
from staff 
where concat(firstName, ' ', middlename, ' ', lastname) Like "%michael peter johnson%"
```

that works but if the name is `"michael johnson"`
it does not work cause the concat name created: `"michael (double space)johnson"` 
So the concat creates two spaces and that does not match.

Does anyone know an alternative way to have a solution for this?

Edit: the idea is that the string "michael peter johnson" is an user input field. so it can not be splitted up in 3 seperate strings a that is not the idea of this search bar

Edit2: I also noticed that if the middlename is "NULL" and that the result of concat(firstName, ' ', middlename, ' ', lastname) with a NU:: is NULL so it would never find it.

Any solution for that?

Thx
Matthy

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
select firstName, middleName, lastName 
from staff 
where concat(firstName, ' ', middlename, ' ', lastname) Like "%michael%peter%johnson%"
```

But I think you want:

```
select firstName, middleName, lastName 
from staff 
where firstName like '%michael%' and
      middleName like '%peter%' and
      lastName like '%johnson%';
```

Or because your database values seem to have spaces, perhaps just:

```
select firstName, middleName, lastName 
from staff 
where trim(firstName) = 'Michael' and
      trim(middleName) = 'Peter' and
      trim (lastName) = 'Johnson';
```

EDIT:

Or, you could do:

```
where concat(trim(firstName), ' ', trim(middlename), ' ', trim(lastname)) Like concat('%', 'michael peter johnson', '%')
```

Comment: well the problem is that the "michael peter johnson" is a user input string. so it needs to look for a full name in a table that has the tree names combined

Comment: thanx the first one would probarly work it it wasnt for the NULL problem see "edit 2"

Answer (score 2):

`Replace` is one more option:

```
select firstName,middleName,lastName 
from staff 
where replace(concat(firstName, ' ', middlename, ' ', lastname), '  ', ' ') Like "%michael peter johnson%"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you serach with michael johnson . do this

```
     select name, midle, last 
     from staff
     where concat(name, ' ', midle, ' ', last) Like "%michael%johnson%"
```

here [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0efe0/3) to play with

EDIT:

```
 select firstName,middleName,lastName 
 from table1
 where (firstName Like "%michael%" AND lastName  LIKE "%johnson%" )
```

Comment: thank you! it would probarly work it it wasnt for the NULL problem see "edit 2"

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most efficient solution but should work for your requirement:

```
select firstName, midlename, lastname 
from staff
where replace(concat(ifnull(firstName, ''), ifnull(middlename, ''), ifnull(lastname, '')), ' ', '') = replace('michael peter johnson', ' ', '');
```